# Linux terminal: Keyboard shortcut for moving across tabs

Tags: command-line

Is there any way to move across the different tabs in linux terminal like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for moving across different tabs in web browsers.

I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> etc... for moving along the ordered tabs. But it will not work more than nine tabs.

Is there any other keyboard shortcut to move across the tabs ?

Comment: It may depend on the specific "linux terminal". Why don't you tell people which "linux terminal" you're using?

Comment: it is cent OS linux terminal.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not for cent os. Such questions are welcome at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution :

For CentOS <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd> will work. It is working fine.